# How to get all list items from all list (list having same name) in various sub sites using rest search api sharepoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-api

I am trying to get all list items in same name lists across the all sub sites having same names list.
example list name: 'Action'

Now I want to get all 'Action' lists items across the all sub sites.

How do I write **rest search api** call for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve your list items by using the following Search REST API Query in case you have used the same content type in the all Action Lists :

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x01007CE30DD1206047728BAFD1C39A85012*'
```

You can get your content type using the following steps :

1. Go to https://site.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/mngctype.aspx
2. Locate the content type of the list
3. Click on it then in the URL you will find e.g :
   ctype=0x01007CE30DD1206047728BAFD1C39A850120

> **Note :** I removed the last 0 from the content type and added a * instead

Comment: Thanks for your help! But if I have same name lists across the subsites which is custom list and their content type is different then what can I do? I want all list items by the list Name not by its content type!

Comment: You can use **contentclass=STS_List Action** instead, for more details please go to the following link : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/02/16/sharepoint-power-searching-using-contentclass/